# Is there a negative impact changing our gcc debug build options from -ggdb3 to -g3 -gdwarf-2?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Our security team has a new code scanner that requires the gcc -g3 -gdwarf-2 build options.  We normally use -ggdb3.  Before I change our default build, I want to make sure this does not negatively impact the debug information or generated executable code.  From the documentation it is hard to tell the difference.  Does anyone have any insight on the differences between these two options?  I'm building on a CentOS 7 distribution with gcc 4.8.

Answer (score 3):

From a brief read of the man page `-ggdb3` will

> use the most expressive format available ( DWARF 2, stabs, or the native format if neither of those are supported), including GDB extensions if at all possible.

whereas `-g3 -gdwarf-2` will

> Produce debugging information in DWARF format (if that is supported). 
>   This is the format used by DBX on IRIX 6. The value of version may be either 2 or 3; 
>   the default version is 3.
>
> Note that with DWARF version 2 some ports require, and will always use,
>   some non-conflicting DWARF 3 extensions in the unwind tables.

So it seems like `-ggdb3` may produce non DWARF 2 debugging info in certain cases and the `-g3 -gdwarf-2` will ensure that DWARF 2 is used.

**EDIT:** The `-g3` is needed because `-gdwarf-x` does not support appending the debug level to it where as `-ggdb` does support appending a debug level.

Comment: I read all of that in the man page.  I understand they are different formats, but what does that mean if/when I need to run gdb to debug a problem or look at a core file?  Do I lose functionality or is it just two different ways of including the same debugging information?  I'm also assuming there is no difference in the generated executable code with the same -o0 optimization option.

Comment: @tfortmann from a quick test I did the executable code was the same, but the `-g3 -gdwarf-2` had some extra labels's that `-ggdb3` did not have (.LCFIx where x is a number) but the data following those labels was the same. The only other thing I noticed is some debug data had different values consistently (for example every `.uleb128 0x19` in `-ggdb3` was matched by a `.uleb128 0xc` in `-g3 -gdwarf-2`) but `-g3 -gdwarf-2` seems more verbose overall.

Comment: Thank you.  This really helps.